# Control direction of sync for client Couchbase installs to Couchbase cloud cluster (or alternative solution)

Tags: database-design, synchronization, couchbase, database, nosql

I am trying to create a setup where I have a series of remote devices creating content that then need to sync up to a central cloud hosted server. My plan is to use a NoSQL option that can sync as fast as possible so that I can have maximum flexibility in data structure.

The issue is that I need to push the data from the end devices, which are spread all over the place on cellular connections. The boxes are AMD x86_64 based units. They need to be able to store data in the case of an issue as well as storing only a limited amount - say 30 days worth of data, where the central cloud will keep data for 3-6 months.

I'm trying to understand how I can achieve this with Couchbase (or an alternative solution). I get how the cluster works, but am trying to work out how to control what data is synced from device to central.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

```
    ---------
    |       |
    | Box 1 |   Sync
    |       |  ------>    -------------------         --------
    ---------             |                 |         |      |
                          |  Cloud cluster  | ----->  | User |
    ---------             |                 |         |      |
    |       |  ------>    -------------------         --------
    | Box 2 |   Sync
    |       |
    ---------
```

Comment: Have you looked at Couchbase Mobile as a possible solution? It does pretty much what you described. As the name implies it's meant for mobile apps, but it may well work for an x86 system as well. CB Mobile is an in-process database with a built-in synchronization mechanism to a central Couchbase server. It does the sync through a server component called the Sync Gateway, which also lets you filter data according to "channels" - topics that different mobile devices may be interested in.   Take a look here: http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

I did check that out but as far as I can tell it is ios and android only with no CentOS/Linux x86 variant. It'd be ace if I could use it in fact because it's so perfect but as far as I can see it wont be able to run on my platform.